# Tables won't display inline windows live mail

Tags: html-table, html-email, windows-live-mail

I'm making a newsletter. I cant get it to work in Windows Live Mail (the outlook lookalike, not the browserversion).

My code is, simplefied, like this:

```
<table width="600">
<tr>
    <td width="600">
        <table width="300"><tr><td>SQUARE 1</td></tr></table>
        <table width="275"><tr><td>SQUARE 2</td></tr></table>

        <table width="300"><tr><td>SQUARE 1</td></tr></table>
        <table width="275"><tr><td>SQUARE 2</td></tr></table>

        <table width="300"><tr><td>SQUARE 1</td></tr></table>
        <table width="275"><tr><td>SQUARE 2</td></tr></table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I am expecting is something like this (which it does in almost all mail programs):

```
[SQUARE 1][SQUARE 2]

[SQUARE 1][SQUARE 2]

[SQUARE 1][SQUARE 2]
```

What Windows Live Mail is giving me:

```
[SQUARE 1][SQUARE 2][SQUARE 1][SQUARE 2][SQUARE 1][SQUARE 2]
```

I've also set the body width (inline) to 600, doesn't matter. And setting square two to 300 didnt either, giving about everything I could `width="600"` didn't matter.
I'm out of ideas, anyone?
When I view the source in my browser, it looks perfect. The squares need to be tables, I cant make `<tr><td>[SQUARE 1]</td><td>[SQUARE 2]</td></tr>` because it is dynamic, it could have an odd amount of squares

Edit: I've checked for htmlerrors, apart from the 'dont use width/height/align inline attributes' it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add a bit of CSS, if you want faux columns:

```
table table
{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I skipped the linebreaks to make them look like 1 object. Besides that, the code you gave isn't different in the actual markup, i've tried the `display:inline/inline-block/inline-table`, all doesnt work. Inline the worst off them. Again, in browser it works fine, its live mail, so a fiddle doesnt matter

Comment: @Martijn The first bit is **your** markup, as posted in your question. I added line breaks to make the misplaced `<td>`s more obvious. The second bit has the corrected markup, and links to an updated jsFiddle example.

Comment: Seeing your fiddle, I *dont* want them inline, thats the whole problem :) And I've fixed the td's, thanks

Comment: If you change your answer to the float option, I'll mark that as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You have repeated the table tag inside the table. Use this instead:

```
<table width="600">
<tr>
    <td width="300">SQUARE 1</td><td width="275">SQUARE 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="300">SQUARE 1</td><td width="275">SQUARE 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="300">SQUARE 1</td><td width="275">SQUARE 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not an option, it's dynamic, could be an odd amount of squares :) I'll update my topic (besides that, this wont work, the table is 600, and the td's combined 575 ;) )